# SetInterval not repeating [Control shifts to an Undefined window in the Chrome Debugger on loop end]

Tags: javascript, debugging, setinterval

The HTML/JS(vanilla) script below displays a **New Random Addition Question** for 5000ms and then displays the answer for the next 3000ms.
After this the **setInterval main loop(8000ms = 5000ms + 3000ms**) should kick in and display a new question and the whole thing should repeat.
However,after the first loop the main loop does not repeat.**The control gets shifted to an UNDEFINED WINDOW in the Chrome Debugger.**
In the setInterval mainLoop , **I have also tried using the actual integer value (8000ms)instead of var time but the looping never happens.**
And also, the **Console does not give any error**.
Please let me know how to get this script to loop.

```js
document.getElementById("runJS1").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("runJS1").innerHTML = "RUNNING";
};
document.getElementById("runJS1").onclick = JS1();

function JS1() {

  // <----------------------DECLARATION-------------------------->
  let time = 8000; //<-- (ms)Time per loop   

  function log(x) {
    console.log(x);
  };

  function consoleClear() {
    console.log('\033[2J');
  };



  //<------------------------- SCRIPT------------------------------> 

  //Create a random number 
  function randNum() {
    let a1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

    return a1;
  }


  // Display question in (time = 5000ms) and then the answer (time =3000ms)
  function add(randN) {
    let a = randN();
    let b = randN();
    let c = randN();
    let sol = a + b + c;
    log(a + ' + ' + b + ' + ' + c + ' = ');

    const timeLoop = 1000; //<-- loop every one second 
    let loop = (time / 1000) - 3; //<---loop count (1 loop/second) 
    const loopInterval = setInterval(function() {

      document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = a + ' + ' + b + ' + ' + c + ' = ';
      log(loop);
      loop -= 1;
      if (loop <= 0) {
        clearInterval(loopInterval);
        document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = a + ' + ' + b + ' + ' + c + ' = ' + sol;
        return false; // <--- Control shifts to a New Undefined Window in the Chrome debugger instead of going back to setinterval loopMain(also tried without using return statement but getting the same result ). 
      }
    }, timeLoop);

  }

  // Loop call to display a NEW question and then the  answer in every 8000ms 
  var loopMain = setInterval(add(randNum), time); // <-- Loops only 1 time (even when 8000ms used instead of var time getting the same result) and never gets the control back from the setInterval loopInterval 


  log("Total Time  = " + time / 1000 + " s");


} //<-- End JS1
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>TestObjects1</title>
  <script src="testJS_objects1.js" defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <button id="runJS1">START</button>
  <h3 id="num"></h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note-Script not working here,but works fine in Chrome).
Execution of the  "function argument(randN)"  passed to the main "add" function can be delayed by using the "[Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/function/bind)" function .
I have modified the above script and now the execution takes place as expected.

```js
// <script src = "testJS_objects1.js" defer></script >
document.getElementById("runJS1").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("runJS1").innerHTML = "RUNNING";
};
document.getElementById("runJS1").onclick = JS1();

function JS1() {

  // <----------------------DECLARATION-------------------------->
  let time = 8000; //<-- Time per loop [displayQuestion +3000ms(displayAnswer)]
  function log(x) {
    console.log(x);
  };

  function consoleClear() {
    console.log('\033[2J');
  };
 


  //<------------------------- SCRIPT------------------------------> 

  //Create a random number 
  function randN(min, max) {
    let a1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    return a1;
  }


  // Display question in (time = 5000ms) and then the answer (time =3000ms)
  function add(randN) {
    let a = randN(0, 100);
    let b = randN(0, 100);
    let c = randN(0, 100);
    let sol = a + b + c;
    log(a + ' + ' + b + ' + ' + c + ' = ');

    const timeLoop = 1000; //<-- loop every one second 
    let loop = (time / 1000) - 3; //<---loop count (1 loop/second) 
    const loopInterval = setInterval(function() {

      document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = a + ' + ' + b + ' + ' + c + ' = ';
      log(loop);
      loop -= 1;
      if (loop <= 0) {
        clearInterval(loopInterval);
        document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = a + ' + ' + b + ' + ' + c + ' = ' + sol;
        log("Wait for 3s");
        console.clear();
        return false;
      }
    }, timeLoop);

  }

  // Loop call to display a NEW question and then the  answer in every 8000ms 
  var loopMain = setInterval(add.bind(this, randN), time); // <-- RandN execution delayed by using the "bind" function


  log("Total Time  = " + time / 1000 + " s");


} //<-- End JS1
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>TestObjects1</title>
  <script src="testJS_objects1.js" defer></script>
  <style>
    body {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 1%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>




</head>

<body>
  <button id="runJS1">START</button>
  <h3 id="num"></h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem lies in calling the `setInterval` at the end of your page

By doing this, as the example below, you call the `add` function instantly with the `randNum` argument. This results in firing the `add` function every 8 seconds with no argument given.

```
var loopMain = setInterval(add(randNum), time);
```

To pass an argument to a `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, use the third parameter of those functions.

```
var loopMain = setInterval(add, time, randNum);
```

Now the `add` function is called every `time` and passes the `randNum` argument to the `add` function.

[Here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Callback_arguments) are more examples of how this works.